# difference between or used with/without bracket

Tags: expressions

What is the key differences between these sentences:

Namespaces defined using object literal notation may be easily extended (or merged) with other objects (or namespaces) such that the properties and functions of both namespaces can be accessible under the same namespace post-merge.

Namespaces defined using object literal notation may be easily extended or merged with other objects or namespaces such that the properties and functions of both namespaces can be accessible under the same namespace post-merge.

Comment: You're seriously asking ELU to tell you whether putting brackets round *(or merged)* and *(or namespaces)* makes any difference to the meaning? No, it doesn't. What's all this *do or die* business?

Comment: I meant extended or merged are different in meaning and extended (or merged) are same in meaning context.

Comment: @ C-link: I don't think it would be a matter of *English* if there were a difference. Presumably you're a programmer, so you know about how expression evaluation is affected by brackets. In your case there simply isn't any logical *scope* for possible different meanings, any more than there would be in **1 + (2 + 3)** as opposed to **1 + 2 + 3** (we'll ignore the possibility that in a contrived computer context you could arrange sneaky side-effects in the evaluations, to make the two expressions return different results! :)

Comment: Regardless of the domain of use and broader context, the two alternatives present semantically different scenarios. Which is to say that the two versions do not mean the same. The author has intentionally used the parentheses (what the OP calls brackets).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't think you can make an argument from arithmetic. That's an entirely different domain.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is one of emphasis. The stuff in parentheses is optional and could have been left out. They could have written it like this:

> Namespaces defined using object literal notation may be easily extended with other objects such that ...

The author no doubt added the stuff in parentheses because he or she thought it was useful information (even though it was inessential) or because they thought it was needed for the sake of strict accuracy.

When you are reading, if you ignore the parenthetical elements, then you are reading the main message.

If you wrote "easily extended or merged" instead of "easily extended (or merged)", then the "or merged" part would become part of the main message. It would become equally as important as "extended".

Comment: You'll probably think I'm just being contrary, but I really do think this is incorrect. Your perspective implies that the writer (who I think is simply being incompetent/careless here) perceives the first (non-bracketed) term in each pair to be the more important one. But that's at odds with the fact that he chose to repeat "namespace" ***twice*** in his "...such that the properties and functions of both" clause. If you were right, he'd  surely have repeated the more important term ("objects", out of that pairing).

Comment: ...to my mind, the only semantic distinction that could apply to this sort of construction would be if the first of each pair *had* to be understood as "linked" to provide one sense, and the second of each pair linked to provide a separate coherent and internally consistent sense. As in, for example, *"ELU users can cast upvotes (or downvotes) to indicate agreement (or dissent)"*. That possibility doesn't apply to OP's example, so far as I can see.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I suspect a definitive answer would require knowledge of the subject matter at hand. I for one am not prepared to get up to get up to speed on JavaScript namespaces :) I've sent a message to the author of the article. Maybe he will weigh in.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript either, but it doesn't require specialist technical knowledge to understand the difference between *extending* and *merging* in a general sense. And I know enough to realise *object* and *namespace* are different concepts, and knowing the precise details of *how* they're different isn't necessary in order to decide whether bracketing could affect the meaning of OP's example. Which as I say, it doesn't and in fact *can't*, unless the writer consistently brackets "namespace" (which he didn't do).

Comment: +1; this is correct. @FumbleFingers: If the writer wants to achieve the appropriate emphasis then they should write effectively.

Comment: @MrHen: Supplementary clauses don't affect the fact that the text explicitly says that a ***namespace*** may be merged with another namespaces ***or an object***. No specialist knowledge is required to infer that *namespaces* and *objects* aren't actually "the same thing". Since the text then refers to ***both namespaces***, it's screamingly obvious that the writer is being to some degree "incompetent/careless". I stand by my analysis - the writing is poor quality, and this analysis is flawed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree. The writing is poor quality. The reason to use parentheses here *would be* to add emphasis. It doesn't actually matter what the poor writing intended for the purposes of teaching people what parentheses mean in this context.

Comment: @MrHen: Perhaps you and dangph here have a different understanding of what "emphasis" could possibly mean in this context. To me, it's obvious ***namespace*** is the more important term, since it's used three times (whereas *objects* is only used once). I don't see how putting one of the three references to *namespace* in brackets can meaningfully have anything to do with "emphasising" anything, since it's already the primary descriptor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Eh, if you are honestly curious we can take it chat. I didn't mean to restart an old argument. I was just adding my opinion.

Comment: @MrHen: Yeah - I'm busy for the next few days, but will pick this one up sometime.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sounds good. Just give me a ping.